# Linq-to-Sql: Use LinqDataSource to programmatically retrieve data

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using a `LinqDataSource` to populate a basic `GridView` in ASP.NET. The user has the ability to filter the results, so I use a few `WhereParameters` and the `Where` within the `LinqDataSource`.

My client has requested an option to export the filtered results to a file. Easy enough to pipe the data into a file, but I would prefer not to rewrite all the where clauses in the codebehind. I would simply like to extract the full set of results, preferably by using the already configure `LinqDataSource`.

When using `LinqDataSource`'s `OnSelect` method, the `e.Result` has the data I'm after, but my `GridView` `PageSize` is set to 20, which means that the `LinqDataSource` (rightly so) only fetches the first 20 records.

Is there anyway to get hold of the entire data set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found the [solution](http://aspguy.wordpress.com/2008/09/28/linqdatasource-with-select-method/) courtesy of AspGuy, Aref Karimi.

The following will retrieve all records by using the `LinqDataSource`'s configuration. Sweet as!

```
    IDataSource source = (IDataSource)myLinqDataSource;
    LinqDataSourceView view = source.GetView("DefaultView") as LinqDataSourceView;

    DataSourceSelectArguments args = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
    args.RetrieveTotalRowCount = view.CanRetrieveTotalRowCount;
    args.SortExpression = view.OrderBy;

    List<MyObject> objects = view.Select(args) as List<MyObjects>;
```